# iOS difference between isKindOfClass and isMemberOfClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class, inheritance

What is the difference between the `isKind(of aClass: AnyClass)` and the `isMember(of aClass: AnyClass)` functions in Swift?

**Original Question in Objective-C**

> What is the difference between the `isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass` and the `isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass` functions?
> I know it is something small like, one is global while the other is an exact class match but I need someone to specify which is which please.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

`isKindOfClass:` returns `YES` if the receiver **is an instance** of the specified class **or** an instance of any class that **inherits** from the specified class.

`isMemberOfClass:` returns `YES` if, and only if, the receiver **is an instance** of the specified class.

Most of the time you want to use `isKindOfClass:` to ensure that your code also works with subclasses.

The [NSObject Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject?language=objc) talks a little more about these methods.

Comment: Can you please clear my below doubt? if ([lbl.textColor isMemberOfClass:[UIColor class]]) { //  Not Memeber
        NSLog(@"Not Memeber");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Not Memeber");
    }
    
  
    if ([imgView.image isMemberOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {// Memeber
        NSLog(@"Memeber");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Not Memeber");
    }

Answer (score 84):

- `isKindOfClass:` indicates whether an object **inherits** from a given class
- `isMemberOfClass:` indicates whether an object **is an instance of** a given class.

---

```
[[NSMutableData data] isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]; // YES
[[NSMutableData data] isMemberOfClass:[NSData class]]; // NO
```

Comment: isKindOfClass will also return YES if the object is an instance of a given class.  In other words isMemberOfClass is a subset of isKindOfClass.

Answer (score 48):

Suppose

```
@interface A : NSObject 
@end

@interface B : A
@end

...

id b = [[B alloc] init];
```

then

```
[b isKindOfClass:[A class]] == YES;
[b isMemberOfClass:[A class]] == NO;
```

Basically, `-isMemberOfClass:` is true if the instance is exactly of the specified class, while `-isKindOfClass:` is true if the instance is exactly of the specified class or if one of the instance's ancestors is of the specified class.

`-isMemberOfClass:` is seldom used.

Comment: But if you have an array of subviews which include UIViews and a UISegmentedControl and you looped through them and set a conditional on class you would need to use isMemberOfClas UIView and isMemberOfClass UISegmentedControl to distinguish between them, no? isKindOfClass would see the UISegmentedControl as a UIView.

Comment: @Pruitlgoe that is very true. You might use isKindOfClass:[UIView class] to ensure that all objects you are dealing with are UIViews but you would need to use isMemberOfClass:[UIView class] and/or isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class] inside some  conditional statement to indicate any distinct implementation of the views based on their immediate instance class

Answer (score 9):

> **[isKindOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:)**: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the
> receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class
> that inherits from that class.
>
> **[isMemberOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass:)**: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the
> receiver is an instance of a given class.

Answer (score 2):

isKindOfClass-> return YES when the object is instance of that class or instance of a class which is inherited from it.

isMemberOfClass: return YES when the object is instance of that class but No in case: instance of a class which is inherited from it.

example is good enough in jtbandes answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of class clusters, isMemberOfClass can give you an answer you might not expect. In many cases your best choice is more likely to be -(BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(SEL)aSelector or - (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol*)aProtocol. I.e, it's better to test these if they can answer your need rather than testing class/subclass.

See apple doc for NSObject class and protocol:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject