# Objective-C class_conformsToProtocol() bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, protocols

I have come across some strange behavior in my iPhone Objective-C app.

I am using some code to test an object:

```
if (!class_conformsToProtocol([someVar someFunctionThatReturnsAClass], @protocol(MyProtocol)))
     [NSException raise:@"Invalid Argument" format:@"The variables returned by 'someFunctionThatReturnsAClass' Must conform to the 'myProtocol' protocol in this case."];
```

Oddly, when I have a class that looks like this:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject<MyProtocol>

...

@end

@interface SubClass : BaseClass

...

@end
```

And when I call this fragment: `class_conformsToProtocol([SubClass class], @protocol(MyProtocol))`, it returns `NO`.

Also, this code fails:

```
class_conformsToProtocol([NSString class], @protocol(NSObject)); // also returns NO
```

While this code returns `YES`:

```
[NSString conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSObject)];
```

Is there anything I am missing in the docs? 
Or is this a bug of some sort? (I am on iOS 4.2 if that matters any).

Comment: Wow, this is *interesting*...

Comment: Not a bug. `class_conformsToProtocol()` does not inspect superclasses. This is by design, since it's trivial to iterate superclasses.

Comment: It's the same kind of difference as between [isKindOfClass vs isMemberOfClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass). In this case, you're looking for the `conformsToProtocol:` method (you can call in on the Class you're getting).

Comment: I actually came here looking for a way to check the conformance of subclasses to a protocol -- ignoring parent class conformance (or vice versa), so thanks for bringing this up! :)

Comment: @ethanB Obviously I knew the proper method to call, as it was in my post, and every other answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSObject`'s [`conformsToProtocol:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCGJEI) method.

Here's an experiment I tried:

```
@protocol MyProtocol

- (void) doSomething;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyProtocol>
{
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void) doSomething { 
}

@end

@interface MyOtherClass : MyClass
{

}

@end

@implementation MyOtherClass

- (void) doSomething {
}

@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    MyClass *obj_one = [MyClass new];
    BOOL one_conforms = [obj_one conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];

    MyOtherClass *obj_two = [MyOtherClass new];
    BOOL two_conforms  = [obj_two conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
    NSLog(@"obj_one conformsToProtocol: %d", one_conforms);
    NSLog(@"obj_two conformsToProtocol: %d", two_conforms);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
obj_one conformsToProtocol: 1
obj_two conformsToProtocol: 1
```

Whereas:

```
MyOtherClass *obj_two = [MyOtherClass new];
BOOL conforms_two = class_conformsToProtocol([obj_two class], @protocol(MyProtocol));
NSLog(@"obj_two conformsToProtocol: %d", conforms_two);
```

Output:

```
obj_two conformsToProtocol: 0
```

Verdict:

**This is a bug with `class_conformsToProtocol`, use the `conformsToProtocol:` method of `NSObject`**

**Unlike `class_conformsToProtocol`, `NSObject`'s `conformsToProtocol:` method will check superclasses as well.**

Answer (score 15):

If there's a bug here, it's in the documentation.

According to the source, `class_conformsToProtocol()` uses `class_copyProtocolList()` and then tests each resulting protocol against the parameter. `class_copyProtocolList()` is documented as only returning protocols that the given class adopts, but not protocols adopted by superclasses. `class_conformsToProtocol()` therefore only tests if the given class adopts a protocol and not if its superclasses do.

The documentation bug is that `class_conformsToProtocol()` doesn't state this behavior. However, the documentation *does* state that you should generally not use that function, but instead use `NSObject`'s `conformsToProtocol:` method instead.

Comment: This is interesting, but you hit the nail on the head.  Generally you really should never use C functions if there is an Objective-C function that does the same thing.  Ex objc_loadModules vs NSBundle