# Why is __NSCFDictionary not a kind of class NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

During a `JSON` parsing (done with AFNetwork json getter), I have this snippet of code:

```
if (![[data class] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    DLog(@"%@ was not kind of class NSDictionary",[data class]);
    return;
}
```

But for some reasons, the `If` sentence becomes true, and the function returns:

```
> __NSCFDictionary was not kind of class NSDictionary
```

But shouldn't `__NSCFDictionary` be specifically kind of class `NSDictionary`? or if this is the wrong way of validating, how do I do it then ?

## UPDATE :

I tried turning it around, like so :

```
        if (![[NSDictionary class] isKindOfClass:[data class]]) {
            DLog(@"%@ was not kind of class NSDictionary",[data class]);
            return;
        }
```

Still doesn't work:

> __NSCFDictionary was not kind of class NSDictionary

Comment: Please provide a link to `AFNetwork`.

Comment: Done :) http://afnetworking.com

Comment: It looks like you are getting an `__NCSFDictionary` because `AFNetworking` makes use of `NSJSONSerialization` (look at the code).  There are related questions that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156835/what-is-an-nscfdictionary and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300461/how-to-get-data-thats-inside-nscfdictionary-returned-by-slrequest-on-osx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:)

```
isKindOfClass:
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class. (required)
```

You are using

```
[data class]
```

which will return a string.. you have to use the object/instance only i.e

```
if (![data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
```