# Data conversion from JSON results as NSDictionary[] throws EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION runtime error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following JSON being received in my Swift code, after being parsed as a NSDictionary. In my function I am trying to extract the JSON objects in "results" block as NSDIctionary[], but this is throwing a run-time error. I don't understand why, as this was working just a few days earlier.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "The National",
        "slug": "thenational",
        "facebook_url": "https://www.facebook.com/thenationalofficial/",
        "twitter_url": "https://twitter.com/The_National",
        "profile_image": "http://example.staging.com/media/profile_image/thumbnail_263x263/1352756032.jpg",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Mayer Hawthorne",
        "slug": "mayerhawthorne",
        "facebook_url": "https://www.facebook.com/MayerHawthorne",
        "twitter_url": "https://twitter.com/MayerHawthorne",
        "profile_image": "http://example.example.com/media/profile_image/thumbnail_263x263/1352755133.png",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "I Play Maracas",
        "slug": "iplaymaracas",
        "facebook_url": "",
        "twitter_url": "",
        "profile_image": "http://staging.wedemand.com/images/en/img-list-home.gif",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
            "_demanded_by": null,
            "demand_url": "http://ec2-54-86-17-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com/artists/20/?demand=1&access_token={}",
            "dismiss_url": "http://ec2-54-86-17-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com/artists/20/?demand=0&access_token={}"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "35",
        "name": "Black SuperHeros",
        "slug": "blacksuperheros",
        "facebook_url": "",
        "twitter_url": "",
        "profile_image": "http://staging.example.com/images/en/img-list-home.gif",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "49",
        "name": "Ayman Elgadi",
        "slug": "aymanelgadi",
        "facebook_url": "",
        "twitter_url": "",
        "profile_image": "http://staging.example.com/images/en/img-list-home.gif",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "8874",
        "name": "Lauri",
        "slug": "lauri",
        "facebook_url": "http://www.facebook.com/hughlaurieblues",
        "twitter_url": "http://twitter.com/hughlaurieblues",
        "profile_image": "http://staging.example.com/media/profile_image/thumbnail_263x263/lauri_profilepic.jpg",
        "_type": "artist",
        "resource_uris": {
        }
    }
]
}
```

My IOS-Swift code receives the NSDictionary object after being parsed by AFNetworking lib and passes to the function which casts the results array as NSDictionary[], is now throwing run-time error, while earlier this was working.

```
(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

var jsonResult: NSDictionary = responseObject as NSDictionary
```

this jsonResult is passed to the function below which tries to cast as NSDictionary[]

```
let allResults: NSDictionary[] = results["results"] as NSDictionary[]
```

**UPDATE**: 
I printed the class of the results object as it is being returned as __NSCFDictionary.

Here [What is an NSCFDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156835/what-is-an-nscfdictionary) is a discussion regarding this and says to use this just like NSDictionary, but in my case its not working.

Comment: please provide a code how you parse this json with swift

Comment: Try printing out its class before the cast.

Comment: Try to print 'jsonResult' before, does it have 'results' key

Comment: @Kevin Hey I printed the class and its __NSCFDictionary.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Yes the jsonResult is perfect. no problems with that I think. The strange this is that this was working earlier, but now its throwing run-time error.

Comment: That means it's a dictionary, not an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Lookup "casting", that is _not_ what you are doing. You are performing a data conversion from JSON bytes to an `NSDictionary` -r `NSArray`.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this question was downvoted? It doesn't promote learning when this is done without any explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `results` is not a dictionary in your JSON, it is an array. You should get it with something like this;

```
let allResults: NSArray = results["results"] as NSArray
```

Comment: I have tried casting as an NSArray, but that also throws run-time error.

Comment: What? It's not an array of arrays, is it?

Comment: If anything, it would be a single `NSArray`, NOT a dictionary of them. @srinivas try without the `[]`.

Comment: @ujell hey thanks! awesome that got rid of the run-time error. thank you!