# Object is subclass of NSMutableDictionary but crashes on mutate method (NSJSONSerialization)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

Run this code:

```
NSData *jsonData = [@"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)result;
    [dict setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"baz"];
}
```

And you get this exception from the `setObject` call:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

When parsing JSON with a top-level dictionary object, `NSJSONSerialization` returns an immutable dictionary object that says it's a an `NSMutableDictionary` but throws an exception when you try to mutate it.

I know I can pass the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option to get mutable containers.  But what is going on here under the hood?  Why does a class say it's a mutable subclass but then behave as if it's immutable?

**Edit to clarify question**: I know there are several ways to make this code work.  I could call `mutableCopy` on the result or use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option to get mutable results.  The point here is that an object says its type is `NSMutableDictionary` or a subclass thereof, and then it causes a crash when I try to mutate it.  Why does this behavior exist?  Should it be considered a bug?  Or is this some expected quirk of the Objective-C runtime?

Comment: I am not subclassing `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: You are confusing "subclass of" and "instance of" in your question title.

Comment: Take a look at the section on **Object Mutability** in Apple's [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html) guide. One of the subheads reads: **Use Return Type, Not Introspection**. Here's an excerpt: "[Y]ou should not make assumptions about whether an object is mutable based on class membership. Your decision should be guided solely by what the signature of the method vending the object says about its mutability."

Comment: Class clusters may seem weird, but they allow Apple's engineers to do some very valuable performance optimizations on heavily used classes.

Comment: The return type from NSJSONSerialization, in the absence of the mutable option, will ALWAYS be non-mutable.

Comment: (Understand that the difference between a mutable and non-mutable NSDictionary/NSArray is merely a flag in the header.  Very often the object starts out mutable and is "flipped" in the `init` routine after initialization is complete.  Most likely NSJSONSerialization makes use of this feature.)

Comment: @jlehr - It is unfortunate that the mutable/non-mutable classes do not provide an `isMutable` interface or whatever, to allow this to be tested at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're trying to set the object for key on `result` (your NSCFDictionary -- immutable) not `dict` (your cast NSMutableDictionary).

Instead, try:

```
NSData *jsonData = [@"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [result mutableCopy];
    [dict setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"baz"];
}
```

The reason result is passing as true when you're trying to determine if it fits NSMutableDictionary class, is because NSCFDictionary is a class cluster that matches both NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary. (see [What is an NSCFDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156835/what-is-an-nscfdictionary)).

In essence (in that if statement), you aren't actually checking at all whether the NSCFDictionary is mutable or not -- you're simply checking that it is a subclass (or member class) of NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: But why is he getting into that if? Then it should already be a NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: It's the same object, so it doesn't matter.  But I'll update the question to address that oddity.

Comment: I was in the process of an edit with those details - see update

Comment: It still crashes with the same exception if I do it with `dict` instead.

Comment: A cast operator can't change an object's type at runtime, so the cast in your example won't make the code behave any differently than it did before. Instead, you send send a `mutableCopy` message to the original dictionary, and work with the mutable instance.

Comment: Ah! It does at that. Almost missed it. You can't simply cast immutable to mutable; you have to create a mutableCopy. See updated code.

Comment: Nope, make a mutable copy of `result`.

Comment: The point though is that this seems to break the assumption that any subclass of class X will do anything that X will.

Comment: @Mr.Jefferson tbh, it feels more like a hack for Objective-C to handle JSON via NSCFDictionary. It is what it is. When in doubt, explicitly cast everything, or do an if/else to check that the resulting JSON is NSDictionary or NSArray kind of class.

Comment: Apple hides the implementation details of class clusters, but in this the current implementation uses instances of `NSCFDictionary` to represent both mutable and immutable instances. The `NSCFDictionary` may be using an internal state flag to determine whether it's mutable, though I'm not sure of that. So `isKindOfClass` responds `YES` for both types. Class clusters can be a little weird.

Comment: @remus Actually, no, it's better to take the opposite approach -- avoid using casts in Objective-C, because they mask the reality of what's going on, and don't check for mutability because that involves looking for private implementation details that are essentially unknowable.

Comment: @jlehr I was trying to convey that lol.. I meant "don't cast it", check if it's a dictionary or array, then create a mutable copy if required.

Comment: @remus Also, please correct your example -- it doesn't make sense at the moment. You're sending `mutableCopy` to an immutable dictionary *after* you try to mutate it and ignoring the mutable dictionary that's returned. As I said earlier, you need to send `mutableCopy` to `result`, not `dict`.

Comment: @remus Don't forget to remove the cast. It's *really* pointless now.