# Problems adding key/values to a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

Fairly new to this. I am trying to add some value/keys to an array that already has value/keys.

The itemsArray contains the json and is derived from the variable json which is a parameter passed to the method from a rest api call.

This is the code I am using and it aborts (at [i setobject] with **[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'**

```
NSMutableDictionary  *itemsArray = [json objectForKey:@"items"];
for ( NSMutableDictionary *i in itemsArray) {      
     [i setObject:@"FirstValue" forKey:@"parents"];                       
 }
```

All this should do is add in the key called parents for each item in the dictionary.

Now if I hard code the value/keys  to the mutable dictionary itemsArray - it works fine.  Its just when I use the variable json which is passed as a parameter and obtained from a call to a rest api.  So the issue is likely that itemsArray contains a immutable json object even though itemsArray is mutable.

The question I have is how do I make the json object mutable (assuming that will cure it) so it will work.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer right in the error message: `itemsArray` is a `NSDictionary` not an `NSMutableDictionary`. See the answer to [What is an NSCFDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156897/1298400) for more details.

How did you create `json`? You need to make sure it contains an `NSMutableDictionary` for the key `@"items"`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a mutable dictionary from your itemsArray. Something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [i mutableCopy];
```

You can then add objects to it as you'd like.