# Transform NSCFDictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

My App gives me a NSCFDictionary as output. But I Need a NSDictionary. Can you say me how to transform it. 
Thanks!

Please in Objective-C.

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156835/what-is-an-nscfdictionary

Comment: An `NSCFDictionary` **is** an `NSDictionary`.