# iOS-How to solve NSCFDictionary gridTitle unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I subclassed a `UICollectionViewCell`, populate the user interface with gridItem

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary gridTitle]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4a76ec0'
>            *** First throw call stack:
>            (0x1829dad8c 0x181b945ec 0x1829e8098 0x1829e05c8 0x1828c641c 0x100e8712c 0x100e8a4f0 0x18c701fb8 0x18c6e7454 0x18c6e0790
>   0x18c5af770 0x186b5125c 0x186b553ec 0x186ac1aa0 0x186ae95d0
>   0x186aea450 0x182982910 0x182980238 0x182980884 0x1828a0da8
>   0x184883020 0x18c88178c 0x100e6ae54 0x182331fc0)
>            libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView 
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *gridCell = nil;
            HDZGoodsGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:HDZGoodsGridCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.gridItem = _gridItem[indexPath.row];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            gridCell = cell;
    }
    return gridCell;
}

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class HDZGridItem;
@interface HDZGoodsGridCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong , nonatomic)HDZGridItem *gridItem;

@end


#import "HDZGoodsGridCell.h"
#import "HDZGridItem.h"
#import "UIColor+HDZColorTranslation.h"
#import <UIImageView+WebCache.h>
@interface HDZGoodsGridCell()

/* imageView */
@property (strong , nonatomic)UIImageView *gridImageView;
/* gridLabel */
@property (strong , nonatomic)UILabel *gridLabel;
/* tagLabel */
@property (strong , nonatomic)UILabel *tagLabel;

@end
@implementation HDZGoodsGridCell
#pragma mark - Setter Getter Methods
- (void)setGridItem:(HDZGridItem *)gridItem
{
    _gridItem = gridItem;
    // !!! The following line of code crashes !!!
    _gridLabel.text = gridItem.gridTitle;


    _gridLabel.text = gridItem.gridTitle;
    _tagLabel.text = gridItem.gridTag;
    _tagLabel.hidden = (gridItem.gridTag.length == 0) ? YES : NO;
    if (_gridItem.iconImage.length == 0) return;
    if ([[_gridItem.iconImage substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
        [_gridImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gridItem.iconImage]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_49_11"]];
    }else{
        _gridImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_gridItem.iconImage];
    }
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUpUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setUpUI
{
    _gridImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _gridImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self addSubview:_gridImageView];

    _gridLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _gridLabel.font = Font13;
    _gridLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:_gridLabel];

    _tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _tagLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
    _tagLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _tagLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:_tagLabel];
}
@end
```

Comment: show me your code on HDZGridItem.

Comment: You are calling `setGridItem` with a Dictionary instead of a `HDZGridItem`.

Comment: You need to add a better description

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary gridTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4a76ec0

means that you tried to call the method `gridTitle` on a `__NSCFDictionary` which simply is a [Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7156835/2442804). Now we can look at where you try to call `gridTitle` in your code: Inside `setGridItem` on the passed argument `gridItem` which is supposed to be a `HDZGridItem`. That means that you actually pass in a Dictionary instead of a `HDZGridItem` when calling that method.

Comment: Thanks ，This problem has plagued me for a long time