# iOS -- distinguish an NSDictionary from an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following code fragment:

```
NSString* value = @"value";
NSString* key = @"key";
NSMutableDictionary* foo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSDictionary* bar = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSAssert([bar isKindOfClass: [NSMutableDictionary class]], @"");   // passes the assert as both are NSCFDictionary;
NSAssert([bar respondsToSelector: @selector(setValue:forKey:)], @"");   // passes the assert because it NSCFDictionary does respond to the selector
[foo setValue:value forKey:key];   // no problem, foo is mutable
[bar setValue:value forKey:key];   // crash
```

So if I have an object which is either an `NSDictionary` or an `NSMutableDictionary`, short of a try block (which I'd rather avoid), how can I tell the difference?

Comment: You probably want to be using -setObject:forKey:, not -setValue:forKey:.

Comment: Do you have a real-world example of when you'd have a dictionary and not be sure whether it is mutable?

Comment: Just wanted to add that [bar respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forKey:)] DOES NOT work.

Comment: @quixoto `-setValue:forKey:` is a method of `NSMutableDictionary`, not just KVC, see the Apple docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSAssert([bar isMemberOfClass: [NSMutableDictionary class]], @"");
```

Comment: Works in iOS 6+.  Fails grossly in iOS 5.x and below.  Keep that in mind when using.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you're inside main this will fail. Use NSCAssert instead.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, you can't easily tell the difference without a `@try` block. Standard practice is as follows:

- If you want to check whether it's mutable in order to avoid someone passing you an unexpectedly mutable object and then mutating it out from under you, `copy` the dictionary. If it's really non-mutable, the frameworks will optimize that into a `retain`. If it really *was* mutable, then you probably wanted a copy anyway.
- If you need a mutable dictionary, declare your method parameters to require one. Simple as that.
- In general, trust that people won't try to mutate objects unless specifically told they were mutable.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually, all you need to do is test against the member of the class, like this:

```
if ([bar isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]){
    [bar setValue:value forKey: key];
}
```

[iPhone SDK difference between isKindOfClass and isMemberOfClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass)

Comment: This doesn't actually work, unfortunately. It's a class cluster, and you can get `__NSCFDictionary` here, as the OP points out, which fails this test.

Comment: As the link I point to shows, there is a difference between what the OP wrote as an example and what I wrote. OP checks for class equality with `isKindOfClass:`, here I check with `isMemberOfClass:`. Although I haven't tested it, it should be `false` if bar is an `NSDictionary`. See this link for better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653948/267892

Comment: Then perhaps you should test it. :) It doesn't work-- the membership test fails for both NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary, since neither is the actual class of the object examined.

Comment: Then what is the actual class of NSMutableDictionary and NSDictionary?

Comment: Just do this to find out: `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] class]);` What you'll see is the underlying private class that the framework creates for *both* mutable and regular dictionaries. You can read more in this doc section under "Class Clusters": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34 These don't always play nicely with explicit class membership tests, as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to guarantee that a dictionary is mutable, you should:

- create it as mutable if you are the one initializing it
- turn it into a mutable instance with the -[NSDictionary mutableCopy] method, for example if you're calling an API that returns an NSDictionary. Note that mutableCopy increments the retain count; you need to release this instance if you are using manual reference counting.

Determining whether an NSDictionary is mutable before attempting to modify its keys and/or values can be considered an example of a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), indicating that there's a deeper problem that should be solved. In other words, you should always know whether a given dictionary instance is NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary. The code should be clear on that point.

Comment: Nice in theory, but in practice these situations do occur.  For example, suppose I got it by calling objectAtIndex: on some array, or valueForKey: on some dictionary.  Now you might say that I should be careful about what I put into the array.  That's a fine theory, but shipping code that crashes simply because I don't want to include these checks is not an option.

Comment: You can't always know. When writing unit tests, for example, even if you really do know, it's still a good idea to verify that an object returned by a  method meets expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care if it's mutable, but want to mutate it anyway, you could try this:

```
NSString* value = @"value";
NSString* key = @"key";

NSDictionary* bar = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSLog(@"bar desc: %@", [bar description]);
NSMutableDictionary* temp = [bar mutableCopy];
[temp setValue:value forKey:key];
bar = temp;
NSLog(@"bar desc: %@", [bar description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using @try catch but it only fires once. So it works like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *valuesByIdMutable = (id)self.valuesById;

simplest_block block = ^{
    [valuesByIdMutable setObject:obj forKey:key];
};

@try {
    block();
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    self.valuesById = valuesByIdMutable = [valuesByIdMutable mutableCopy];
    block();
}
```