# NSDictionary (__NSDictionaryI) isMemberOfClass: isKindOfCLass: difference

Tags: ios

I understand the difference between isKindOfClass: and isMemberOfClass: but I came across something I do not understand:

```
-(UIImage *)doSomething:(id)item 
{

    UIImage *image;

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = item;
        NSData *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    } else { // if item is UIImage
        image = item;
    }

    return image;
}
```

If I am using isKindOfClass in this context everything works as expected. If I use isMemberOfClass I get the following crash asking for the size of the image later:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x123456

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x123456'
```

I read other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235965/ios-distinguish-an-nsdictionary-from-an-nsmutabledictionary) but I couldn't find anything that would come closer.

Comment: NSDictionary is a so called class cluster. It uses concrete subclasses (like __NSDictionaryI for immutable implementations) to abstract away implementation details. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are different and their difference is documented. Using `isKindOfClass:` will return YES for subclasses whereas `isMemberOfClass:` won't. Since NSDictionary is a class cluster (uses private subclasses internally) will get different results when using the two (because the instance would be a private subclass (in your case `__NSDictionaryI`).

When using `isMemberOfClass:`, this is what happens in your case:

1. The argument `item` is a private dictionary subclass
2. Evaluating `isMemberOfClass:` returns NO
3. The dictionary is assigned to a UIImage variable
4. The UIImage variable is returned (but it really contains a dictionary)
5. You try and use that "image" and when the system asks for the image size, the dictionary doesn't respond to `size` and throws an exception.