# Getting property of an array with viewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I got an array with viewcontrollers from different types, named `viewControllersArray` so first I check if the type is correct (QuestionViewController) and then I want to print out the property.

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i<viewControllersArray.count; i++) { 
if ([[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[QuestionViewController class]])    {
    NSLog(@"%@",((QuestionViewController*)[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer ); 
    }
}
```

However this just shows me (null) instead of the NSString property.

**EDIT**

What I got so far is this:

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i<viewControllersArray.count; i++) { 
    if ([[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[QuestionViewController class]]){
        NSLog(@"IDENT: %@", [[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] ident]);
        NSLog(@"ANSWER: %@", [[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] getQAnswer]);
    }
}
```

the second NSLog (getQAnswer) works. getQAnswer is a method in QuestionViewController. The first NSLog (ident) shows incorrect output (null), this is the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ident;
```

Comment: Once could you please print your viewControllersArray ???

Comment: why did you type cast it to QuestionViewController?

Comment: If I don't typecast, it shows me: "Property 'getQAnswer' not found on object of type 'id'"

Comment: [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:yourIndex] getQAnswer]; if(UINavigationController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typecasted to `QuestionViewController`

Use

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] getQAnswer]);
```

**EDIT**:

As per your comment `viewControllersArray[0]` gives you `SendViewController`.

You should change

```
isKindOfClass:
```

to

```
if( [[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:i] class] == [QuestionViewController class])
```

Comment: I got an error when I do that: "Property 'getQAnswer' not found on object of type 'id'"

Comment: what object is strored in viewContorllerArray?

Comment: Your second answer doesn't give an error, but it still gives me (null). I added some viewController like:         [viewControllersArray addObject: questionViewController]; for example

Comment: <SendViewController: 0x86989b0>

Comment: Fine. Are you sure, `SendViewController` contains `getQAnswer` ?

Comment: No, SendViewController doesn't contain getQAnswer. Thats why I got the for-loop, to check for "QuestionViewController" and this one does got the getQAnswer property.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya you made him print the first object in the array. That is SendViewController. The OP did not say that QuestionViewController object was the first object in the array. Thats why they have put in a loop.

Comment: @lostInTransit: That is why asked, now he came to know even though class is not same, it resulted to YES, and enterd. Coz he use  iskindofClas:

Comment: It seems to work now, I've made a method in QuestionViewController which returns the NSString. However when I just want to grab the property (without a method) it shows (null)

Comment: The problem isn't the loop, this works and your answer also does work. The problem is that when I want to get the property string it shows (null) instead of the property string

Comment: @AnoopVaidya OP never said that the first viewcontroller went into the if condition!

Comment: @Shinonuma do you have a getQAnswer property in your VC or just qAnswer? (check my answer)

Comment: do me a favor, inside `if` use nslog([viewControllersArray[0] class]); and tellme the output

Comment: @Shinonuma: in your edit, `@property (strong, nonatomic) *ident;` no datatype/class is set for ident

Comment: I've found my mistake, somewhere in my program I set ident to nil, such a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you get a null, that could only mean that the value of qAnswer is not set. If the object wasn't a type of QuestionViewController, it would not get into the if condition.

Are you sure the value of qAnswer is set? And if you are using a getter/setter, shouldn't you be using `[viewcontroller getQAnswer]` or `viewcontroller.qAnswer` (unless you have a variable called getQAnswer)?

Also is there any view controller in the array which is an object of a subclass of QuestionViewController? If there is, then that viewcontroller will also satisfy the condition and go inside the if condition.

If that is a case, try using `isMemberOfClass:`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass)

Comment: if getQAnswer is not there, compiler will show error, and he cant even compile it. Now he is executing it.