# What's the best way to assign NSArray elements to the appropriate objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

If I have objects from the following 3 classes in a NSArray, what's the best way to assign the array elements to the appropriate object?

```
@interface Simple : NSObject 
@interface Intermediate : Simple 
@interface Advanced : Simple
```

I'd like to loop through the NSArray and if the 2nd element of the array is Intermediate and the 5th element is Advanced, I want to assign them to variables of Intermediate and Advanced respectively. This lets me call methods in the derived class that are not defined in the base class.

Let me know if there is a better to go about this than having an NSArray contain different objects (I'm still interested in knowing the answer to the original question)!

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's hard to tell not only what you're trying to do, but why.

Comment: I have a tab bar that links out to various documentation forms. The simple forms let you load/save/edit fields, the intermediate form can dynamically add/remove/edit other fields within the form (scripting), while the advanced form can add/edit/remove fields from other _forms_. They all inherit from Simple because this lets me avoid reimplementing common infrastructure; the form objects are stored in an array that corresponds to the tab bar.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the class of the object while looping using either `isMemberOfClass:` or `isKindOfClass:` (more about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass)).

That said, if - as I suspect - the three classes share common logic, why don't you just make `Simple`, `Intermediate` and `Advance` subclass of a common ancestor, called - say - `Difficulty`, and then use variables of `Difficulty` type?

You could then assign any object in the array to the `Difficulty` variables regardless of the subclass.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this, but here goes my 2 questions:  
1. Can't Simple be considered the common ancestor here (since Intermediate and Advanced both derive from it)?
  
2. If I used a Difficulty variable, that still wouldn't let me access methods that were defined only in Advanced, would it?
  
Outside of having an if condition that checks isKindOfClass, I can't think of a "nicer" way to do #2.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test what type of class the array entry is via:

```
id myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];

if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[Simple class]]) {
    //do something 
} else if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[Intermediate class]]) {
    //do something 
} else if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[Advanced class]]) {
    //do something 
}
```