# NSDate isMemberOfClass: [NSDate class] returns false?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nsdate

this is bizarre. The following if statement is failing. What could be wrong?

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

 if ([date isMemberOfClass: [NSDate class]]) {
    // Not executed.
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `isKindOfClass:` in place of `isMemberOfClass:`? You shouldn't need to use the more generic version of the two, but it might provide the result you're looking for.

Comment: have you looked into this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass ?

Comment: @Mr.T this is not a duplicate of that thread. OP is asking a question regarding an issue they have run into while using those methods, not what the difference between the two is.

Comment: @Jonathan I see your point, but you see OP's problem too, right? I just tried `isKindOfClass` and `isMemberOfClass` on `UIView` and both hold up.

Comment: It may not be a perfect duplicate as the question is different, but the link I provided will answer to this question in all aspects,which makes me think this one as duplicate.

Comment: moreover I alone cant close this question as duplicate. I just voted it as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens  that classes like `NSArray`,  `NSDictionary`, `NSString` and
`NSData` are  class clusters.  This concept is  explained better  in the
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4-SW1), and it means that you will not get a direct instance
for that class.

Due  to the  variety of  "data" to  be handled,  the class  has internal
specialised  subclasses; and  when you  create  an instance  it will  be
determined which  of these internal  subclasses is the best  option, and
your object will  then be an instance of that  subclass (not of `NSData`
itself).

In this case, if you need to check that, use `isKindOfClass:` which will
be true for subclasses as well.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

if ([date isKindOfClass: [NSDate class]]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

**Edit**:
Just as an additional  example, calling `NSStringFromClass([obj class])`
in these objects:

```
NSData   * data     = [NSData data];
NSData   * str_data = [@"string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSNumber * n_bool   = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSNumber * n_int    = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];
NSArray  * array    = [NSArray array];
```

Results in:

```
_NSZeroData
NSConcreteMutableData
__NSCFBoolean
__NSCFNumber
__NSArrayI
```

Comment: You beat me to it. (voted). I often have trouble remembering which is which, isMemberOfClass and isKindOfClass, and have to check the docs if I haven't used them in a while.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, and I personally don't use them much too. But I think "member" already brings a more restrict sense than "kind". I think you can remember that if `A` is almost like `B`, but not exactly equal, we can say that `A` is _kind of_ `B`.... So the _kind_ version is more broader. I can't think of a better mnemonic than that now. Maybe others will. The more strange or unreal it is, the better we will remember it :-D

Comment: When I think about it I use the term "member" to be a synonym for instance. But then I spend 2 months without using it and forget my mnemonic.

Comment: thanks,  this is pretty much what I  suspected.

Answer (score 0):

> NSDate is a class cluster.

That means when you try to do that underneath it's different class (concrete implementation of NSDate) :)

More on [class clusters here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH7-SW1)