# What is _PFArray?

Tags: objective-c

I just printed an `NSArray` in the debugger and this is what it returned:

```
<_PFArray 0x12ff90200>(
   // some data was in here
)
```

But what is a `_PFArray`?

Answer (score 5):

It's a subclass of `NSArray` used by the Core Data framework.

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` is  a class cluster. This  pattern is used extensively  in the
implementations,  and  largely discussed  in  other  questions too.  One
example here: [NSDate isMemberOfClass: [NSDate class] returns false?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466567/557306)

So, in  short, it is  a subclass used  to an specific  internal purpose.
Long answer, check the linked answer to begin reading on the subject.