# Comparing of two classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I am comparing two classes using property `isKindOfClass`, but doesn't seem to working. I have logged the outputs which seem same, but I don't understand why aren't they working.

```
UIView *childView = [view subviews][j-1];
NSLog(@"childview class: %@", childView.class);
NSLog(@"childview.class class: %@", [childView.class class]);
NSLog(@"sfidimmer button class: %@", [SFIDimmerButton class]);


if([childView.class isKindOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]){
   NSLog(@"iskindofclass");
   curFrameSize = dimFrameWidth;
}
```

Output of nslogs:

```
childview class: SFIDimmerButton

childview.class class: SFIDimmerButton

sfidimmer button class: SFIDimmerButton
```

The control doesn't go inside if conditon, can you please let me know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use of Class  do like as ..

```
if([childView isKindOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]){

    // do your stuff here  ..
}
```

hope it help you .

Comment: thanks, but can you explain what is happening when I am using of class ?

Comment: @Masood This should help you to figure out the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653947/656600 also look at leo's answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your error

`Self.class` return class Object,while you using `isKindOfClass` which is used to check instance of class

You can check if a object it is an instance of that class using `isKindOfClass` as above answer said.

Document

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.

You can also check class using

```
[childView.class isSubclassOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiving class is a subclass of, or identical to, a given class.

Answer (score 1):

Your check is wrong. You should call isKindOfClass: on object and not on class of object.

So rather than checking for

```
if([childView.class isKindOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]){
    NSLog(@"iskindofclass");
    curFrameSize = dimFrameWidth;
}
```

Try this instead

```
if([childView isKindOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]){
    NSLog(@"iskindofclass");
    curFrameSize = dimFrameWidth;
}
```

You can also use `isMemberOfClass`, but most of the time you want to use `isKindOfClass`: to ensure that your code also works with subclasses.

`isKindOfClass`: returns YES if the receiver is an instance of the specified class or an instance of any class that inherits from the specified class.

`isMemberOfClass`: returns YES if the receiver is an instance of the specified class.

Answer (score 0):

Use any object with id datatype, then compare it with Class type. If satisfied, then type cast with Target class.

```
id childView = [view subviews][j-1];
if ([childView isKindOfClass:[SFIDimmerButton class]]) {

    SFIDimmerButton *btnDimmer = (SFIDimmerButton *)childView;
    // perform your action with derived button..
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.
Thanks.