# how to cast or set an object of type id to another type like UIImageView or UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, casting, uiimageview

In the below code, I iterate through entries and they might be of type UIView or UIImageView. I want to do check if the uiComponent is of either the mentioned types, and then I want to proceed using that uiComponent in the code based on 
Whether it is a UIView or UIImageView?

I rote the below code but I can’t use the pointer object

```
uiComponent
```

After having it typed-casted??

Please let me know how to type the uiComponent object to either of the classes UIView or UIImageView and proceed programming using it

**Code**

```
 for (id uiComponent in uiviews) {
            UIView *uiView;
            UIImage *uiImageView;

         if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIView:uiComponent]) {
                uiComponent = (UIView *)uiComponent;
         }
            if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIImageView:uiComponent]) {
            uiComponent = (UIImageView *)uiComponent;
        }

         if (![uiComponent isHidden]) {
            …
    ..
    …
            }
```

Comment: `isKindOfClass:`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/ios-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass ?

Comment: Your casting here isn't doing anything at all (but also isn't necessary). I suspect you have a different problem. When you say "I can't use the pointer object," what do you mean? Your code also defines `uiImageView` as a UIImage (not a UIImageView). It's unclear if this is intentional since the variable is never used. Note that a UIImageView is *also* a UIView, so in all cases it's a UIView. In what way do you intend to use these elements differently if it is a UIImageView vs if it isn't? Why can't you just treat it as a UIView always?

Comment: When I say the casting is doing nothing, I mean that the `(UIView *)` in `(UIView *)uiComponent` has no runtime impact. It just tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing here; please don't raise a warning." After the assignment line, `uiComponent` is exactly the same value it was before, and the compiler still considers it of type `id`. It is identical to the line of code `uiComponent = uiComponent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your local object based on the type, then use it if it's not nil:

```
for (id uiComponent in uiviews) {
    UIView *uiView;
    UIImageView *uiImageView;

    if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIView:uiComponent]) {
        uiView = (UIView *)uiComponent;
    }
    if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIImageView:uiComponent]) {
        uiImageView = (UIImageView *)uiComponent;
    }

    if (uiView) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIView
        if ([uiView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
    if (uiImageView) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIView
        if ([uiImageView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
}
```

Or, since you are already in `if` blocks, you can do it there:

```
for (id uiComponent in uiviews) {
    if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIView:uiComponent]) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIView
        UIView *uiView = (UIView *)uiComponent;
        if ([uiView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
    if ([AQSViewHelper isEntryOfTypeUIImageView:uiComponent]) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIImageView
        UIImageView *uiImageView = (UIImageView *)uiComponent;
        if ([uiImageView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thx..would you please tell me why it is not possible to declare  UIView *uiView;
            UIImage *uiImageView; before the if-statement

Comment: There is really no difference. If you declare them outside the `if` block, you can *use* them outside the `if` block. Without knowing what all you want to do with them, it just seems a little more "organized" to declare them where needed.

Comment: would you please have a look at this question pls : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58771956/how-to-check-if-the-class-is-created-by-user-of-it-is-a-class-provided-in-pobjec?noredirect=1#comment103831953_58771956