# how to check if the class is created by user of it is a class provided in pobjective-c API

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

i have a user-defined class of type CircularDynamicUIView. it is in an array the encompass several views like 'buttonviews, uiimageviews,scrollviews and others.
how to programmatically within a loop to detect this user-defined class. for example: using if-statement

how to check if this class is the class created or developed by the user and not the one that already created by objective-c.

Comment: You can check for a specific class. You can check if it's a subclass of a specific class. You can check it it conforms to a protocol. But there is no way to differentiate between one of "your" classes and a class from a specific framework. You should update your question and clarify what problem you are actually trying to solve so a proper solution to the real issue can be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy noted in comments, you cannot explicitly differentiate between, for example, your custom `CircularDynamicUIView` subclass and a default `UIView` ... but you *can* evaluate in a specific order.

Example (using your previous question):

```
for (id uiComponent in uiviews) {

    if ([uiComponent isKindOfClass:[CircularDynamicUIView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes, it is a CircularDynamicUIView");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No, it is NOT a CircularDynamicUIView");
    }

    // if CircularDynamicUIView is a subclass descendant of UIView
    // this will also be true
    if ([uiComponent isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes, it is a UIView");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No, it is NOT a UIView");
    }

}
```

Since both `if` conditions will be true, you would not want to evaluate the second `if` if the first test was true.

Again, based on your previous question, you could use this approach:

```
for (id uiComponent in uiviews) {
    CircularDynamicUIView *cdView;
    UIView *uiView;
    UIImageView *uiImageView;

    if ([uiComponent isKindOfClass:[CircularDynamicUIView class]]) {
        cdView = (CircularDynamicUIView *)uiComponent;
    } else if ([uiComponent isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        uiImageView = (UIImageView *)uiComponent;
    } else if ([uiComponent isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        uiView = (UIView *)uiComponent;
    }


    if (cdView) {
        // do what you want because it's a CircularDynamicUIView
        if ([cdView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
    if (uiImageView) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIImageView
        if ([uiImageView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
    if (uiView) {
        // do what you want because it's a UIView
        if ([uiView isHidden]) {
            // ...
        }
        // etc ...
    }
}
```